# Ruby array to csv file

Tags: arrays, ruby, excel, csv, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape a table from a webpage and store it into a csv file.(I have to do it this way, so let's skip other suggestions. e.g. excel, non-array solution, etc)

Each row of the table on the webpage is a `tr` tab. If I were to export to excel, I would loop the rows by doing this:

```
.css("tr")[1..-1].each do |line|
```

That would give the correct format in excel, but when I use the array-to- csv approach, each row from the table becomes a column in the csv.  Thus, if there are 10 rows and 20 columns in the table, it will be displayed as 10 col x 1 row (all 20 column values for each row are stored in one single cell) in csv.

I guess it's because the array sees each row as an index and stores the row into each column in the csv file.

Is there a way to get the right format in csv?

current code:

```
category_array = []
page.css("#ctl00_PageData_GridView1").css("td")[0..30].each do |line|
category_name = line.text
category_array.push(category_name)
end
CSV.open('category.csv','w') do |csv|
csv << category_array
end
```

Comment: What's your code inside `do ... end`?

Comment: `category_array = []`
  
`page.css("#ctl00_PageData_GridView1").css("td")[0..30].each do |line|`
  `category_name = line.text
  category_array.push(category_name)
end`

`CSV.open('category.csv','w') do |csv|
  csv << category_array
end`

Comment: Please update your question to include this code snippet.

Comment: Corpus. Code. Expected output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you are doing something wrong with the array like using `<<` over `+`:

```
irb(main):035:0> row = [1]   
irb(main):035:0> result = [] 

irb(main):035:0> result + row
=> [1] # It adds the content of the second array to the first

irb(main):037:0> result.concat(row)
=> [1] # Same as above

irb(main):036:0> result << row
=> [[1]] # It moves the whole array into the other array
```

So maybe you want to use `concat` or `+` instead of `<<`.